# User-Agent in request for IOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, user-agent

Hi i'm developing a android and IOS app . I never set a user-agent header for my API call. (simply use some library to make request and get response) Now my server guys told me that

" We are facing an issue as currently  mobile does not do any authentication when calling esb

Simply states  SytemId=’ABC’

Now we are getting malicious hits from intruders  disguised as mobile and is cauing lot of traffic"

Is this related to user-agent? What should I do now? Any help is much appreciated. I'm not good at security thing

Comment: I think you should talk to your server guys and have them explain what they mean.  But no, it sounds like your problem is you aren't calling some authentication api and getting a proper individual security token.

Comment: Thanks. But the server API does not have any security or authentication. Is there anything I can do from my side? for example setting a user-agent?

Comment: You need to talk to your server people.  There's nothing in what you posted that sounds like this is anything to do with user-agent, which is not a security setting and would not help to prevent people faking being mobile users.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a talk with him. Do you have any suggestion regarding this? Can this because of the transport layer security or certificate? I have just checked the server currently only supports SSL v3 and TLS 1.0 and there are some insecure certificate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you don't set any custom user-agent, The network layer set one user agent based on the device type and ios version in case of iOS app.

So check with the server team what logic they applied for "malicious hit detection".

This link contains some basic strategy that a server applies to detect a request as suspicious,
https://datadome.co/how-to-detect-malicious-bots/

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will check the link. I subspect they don't have any strategy yet

Comment: Hi just learn that android user agent when sent request is null. How can we set default user agent so that the server can recognise and filter the other?